# Is this equality ($\frac{2\tan\alpha}{1+\tan^{2}\alpha}=\sin2\alpha$) true?

Tags: trigonometry

My book thinks that this equality $\frac{2\tan\alpha}{1+\tan^{2}\alpha}=\sin2\alpha$ is true. I beg to differ. I think that this is only true when $\cos\alpha\neq 0$.

*I think this is my book's logic:*

$$\frac{2\tan\alpha}{1+\tan^{2}\alpha}$$

$$=\frac{2\frac{\sin\alpha}{\cos\alpha}}{1+\frac{\sin^2\alpha}{\cos^2\alpha}}$$

$$=\frac{2\frac{\sin\alpha}{\cos\alpha}}{\frac{\cos^2\alpha+\sin^2\alpha}{\cos^2\alpha}}$$

$$=\frac{2\frac{\sin\alpha}{\cos\alpha}}{\frac{1}{\cos^2\alpha}}$$

$$=2\sin\alpha\cos\alpha$$

$$=\sin2\alpha$$

Now that I think about it, when $\cos\alpha=0$, $\tan\alpha$ itself won't be defined, let alone the equality. So, I think I'm correct.

Am I correct?

Comment: Hi, yes when $cosa=0$ then $tana$ is not defined but considering the points in which $tana$ is defined your equation is correct

Comment: An *identity* is an equation that is true on the intersection of the domains of the expressions appearing on the right-hand side and left-hand side.  In the equation you write, the left-hand side is undefined when $\cos \alpha = 0$, so these choices of $\alpha$ are irrelevant for determining that the equation is an identity.  (An equality of functions is only ever meaningful at points where both are defined.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: you are sort of correct.

---

Longer answer:

The equality is true for all values $\alpha$ for which both sides of the equation are defined.

This is a good case of when to be very very careful with mathematical language, both as the readers and writers.

---

In a sense, it is correct to write that the value $\frac{2\tan\alpha}{1+\tan^{2}\alpha}$ is always equal to the value $\sin(2\alpha)$, because implicitly, when we are talking about expressions, it is always assumed we are only talking about the ranges where those expressions are defined - and for all values where $\frac{2\tan\alpha}{1+\tan^{2}\alpha}$ is defined, that value is indeed equal to $\sin(2\alpha)$.

Note that this is a perfectly sensible way of expressing things in mathematics, just as it is perfectly valid to say things like "the square root of a value is nonnegative", even if the more completely correct sentence would be "the square root of a *nonnegative* value is nonnegative".

---

The interesting thing is that, at least to me, the equality would strike me as much more problematic if it was written the other way around, i.e.

$$\sin2\alpha=\frac{2\tan\alpha}{1+\tan^{2}\alpha}.$$

I suppose that implicitly, I always read equations as if the left hand side also defines the range which its variables can take.

---

Another interesting thing is that even if $\cos(\alpha_0)=0$, you can say the following:

$$\lim_{\alpha\to\alpha_0} \frac{2\tan\alpha}{1+\tan^{2}\alpha} = \sin2\alpha_0,$$

which means that the function $$x\mapsto \frac{2\tan\alpha}{1+\tan^{2}\alpha}$$ is a function that can be "continuously expanded" to the function $$x\mapsto \sin(2\alpha).$$

Comment: "The interesting thing is that, at least to me, the equality would strike me as much more problematic if it was written the other way around": Is there any difference between $x=y$  
 and $y=x$ kind sir? I don't understand this part of your answer kind, kind sir. Could you please explain it to me?

Comment: @tryingtobeastoic Like I said, technically, the expressions $x=y$ and $y=x$ are identical. However, personally, I read the expression $f(x)=g(x)$ as follows: For all $x$ in the domain of $f$, the value of $f(x)$ is equal to the value of $g(x)$. In that sense, the expressions $f(x)=g(x)$ and $g(x)=f(x)$ are not completely identical. Note that this is because writing the expression without a quantified variable is, in general, slightly non-rigorous from the start.